# mouse move and click over vlc embed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mouseevent, vlc

I've been searching far and wide for a solution to this, I have a vlc plugin embedded on my pages. I know the "windowless" option exists, but that increases resource usage excessively.

Is there any other way to catch mouse events like click and mouse move over the embedded video in JavaScript?

Any solution to this problem would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is now possible to catch mouse events in a VLC Web Plugin without any local programming knowledge. This method does although require some knowledge of [QML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QML) ([Official Docs](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtqml-index.html)).

You will need to install [WebChimera Plugin](http://www.webchimera.org/) for this to work.

[See Working Demo](http://editor.webchimera.org/mouse_events)